# wxNotebook with different sized content for each tab

Tags: wxwidgets

If I create a wxNotebook and populate it with several pages, the content area of the wxNotebook is the same size on every tab (the size of the page with the largest content). Is there a way to dynamically resize the wxNotebook to only be as large as is needed to contain the Panel in that view, for example when a EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resize the **wxNotebook** but I wasn't able to get the size of the tabs programmatically. I add panels in the notebook, and I know the size of each one of them.
So I connected the event:

```
    m_notebook->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, wxNotebookEventHandler(MyClass::OnTabSelect), NULL, this);
```

and here's an example event listener:

```
void MyClass::OnTabSelect( wxNotebookEvent& event )
{
    wxSize s = GetSize();
    int tabIndex = event.GetSelection();
    s.x = m_tabWidth[tabIndex];
    s.y = m_tabHeight[tabIndex];
    SetSize(s);
    Refresh();
    event.Skip();
}
```